# prepared INSERT statement to get insert_id to use in a second prepared INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, insert-id

Im trying to create my own register form but im having issues with prepared statements.

the idea is to create a prepared statement to insert info into the user table, then from that get the insert_id from the generated content to use in another insert statement

here is a version of my register script

```
  <?php

    $returnedId = '';

    include "includes/dbconnect.php";

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $returnedId = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();

    echo $returnedId;

    $allergystmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'user_allergy' ('user_id', 'allergy_id') VALUES (?, ?)");
    $allergystmt->bind_param('ss', $returnedId, $_POST['check_list']);
    $allergystmt->execute();
    $allergystmt->close();

    header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

the first prepared statement runs correctly and inserts information into the table, after that the $returnId variable is successfully echoed. next in the script is my second prepared statement, when it tries to run im getting the error that says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in D:\filepath\register.php on line 17

it seems that my variable isnt being carried into the second prepared statement.

Comment: You're using `'` instead of backticks (`\``) in your 2nd query.

Comment: You don't need to fetch and reuse the value as `$returnedId`. You can just call MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` natively in the second `INSERT` query.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: best to capture it in PHP. Just in case there's OTHER inserts to be done later.

Comment: @MarcB I took the `header("Location:..)` as an indication that there wouldn't be, but of course valid point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query has syntax errors and failed to `prepare`. Since you have no error handling for database failures like this, your later code just blunders onwards:

```
$allergystmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'user_allergy' ('user_id', 'allergy_id') VALUES (?, ?)");
                                         ^---         ^--^---    ^-- etc...
```

You cannot use `'` quotes on table and field names. `'` indicate strings. None of those field/table names are reserved words, so there is NO need to quote them at at all:

```
$allergystmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_allergy (user_id, allergy_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
if (!$allergystmt) { die($dbh->errorInfo()); }
```

Note the addition of the errorInfo() output. Never assume a DB operation was successful. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: the quote marks did the trick, apologies for the silly mistakes, its the first time ive looked at PHP in nearly 2 years!